# T-SQL Stored Procedure times out when called from C# - Tried Recompiling

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that takes between 5-10 seconds to execute in SQL Server management studio.

When this is called from C#, it times out after 10 mins:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

I have used sp_recompile to recompile the query, also DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear any caches and execution plans to no avail.

I have searched and searched but I have only found answers pointing to what I have tried above. So I am thinking that maybe it is something more obvious that I am missing?

```
public static void Action_StoredProc(SqlConnection conn, Boolean map, string acc) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Action_StoredProc", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@map", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = map;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@acc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = acc;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Did you Dispose the SqlConnection properly?

Comment: Is that 5-10 seconds in management studio the time it takes before results appear, or the complete time taken for it to produce all results?

Comment: AndrásOttó - yup
@Damien_The_Unbeliever - it is a series of update statements so no results to produce, but yes it is 5-10s to complete the entire sp

Comment: any indices on the impacted tables?

Comment: The *difference* is likely explained by differing plan use due to different ARITHABORT settings on the two connections, the *reason* is likely parameter sniffing. Canonical reading on this subject; [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @Alex K This was fixed by using the OPTIMIZE FOR feature of SQL. The query took two parameters: 1. a boolean value that was used once and only in a certain circumstance, and a varchar value that the whole query was based around and used often. By default, the query had been optimized for the boolean value. So the issue was parameter sniffing, and by putting an option at the end of each update statement to OPTIMIZE for the parameter in question the problem was solved. "option(OPTIMIZE FOR (@Par UNKNOWN))" - UNKNOWN because the value is not static

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server Profiler, set a profile running and then run the query in SSMS then from code.

Take a note of the SET statements that are passed from SSMS and your code, my guess is they will different.

Then all you need to do is explicitly set them against your connection in your code or add the differing ones to the top of your SP.

Comment: I will be using the Sql profiler and also looking at parameter sniffing. I will let you know the result, thanks :-)

Comment: This was fixed by using the OPTIMIZE FOR feature of SQL. The query took two parameters: 1. a boolean value that was used once and only in a certain circumstance, and a varchar value that the whole query was based around and used often. By default, the query had been optimized for the boolean value.

So the issue was parameter sniffing, and by putting an option at the end of each update statement to OPTIMIZE for the parameter in question the problem was solved. "option(OPTIMIZE FOR (@Par UNKNOWN))" - UNKNOWN because the value is not static

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation in that a procedure would take less than 1 second to execute via SSMS however running from any code it took 45 seconds to complete.  We loaded up SQL trace and found that the execution plans were different from the procedure running via SSMS and code.  In order to get the right execution plan in both places we recompiled the procedure, altered it, cleared all execution plans in the DB, etc... and still had the issue.

In the end, rebuilding statistics on the primary table used by the procedure then recompiling the procedure forced the execution plan to be the same for both execution methods thus fixing our issue.

Here are the commands:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [TABLE NAME]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_recompile @objname = N''
GO
```